# Download and run sub install - Inno Download Plugin progress bar does not move during download

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

Ok, so I created the following iss but I the progress bar does not move.  I want the setup file to download and run the other setup program.  Everything works fine except the progress bar does not move.

```pascal
#define MyAppName "My Program Setup Downloader"
#define MySetupAppName "My Program Setup.exe"
#define MySetupUrlFolder "https://www.example.com/folder/"
#pragma include __INCLUDE__ + ";" + "c:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Download Plugin\"

[Setup]

AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVerName={#MyAppName}
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes
CreateAppDir=no
Uninstallable=no

#include <idp.iss>

[Code]

var FileName: string;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var DownloadUrl: String;
begin
  FileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#MySetupAppName}');
  DownloadUrl := '{#MySetupUrlFolder}{#MySetupAppName}';
  idpAddFile(DownloadUrl, FileName);
  idpDownloadAfter(wpSelectDir);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer) : boolean;
var ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    Result := Exec(FileName, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    if not Result then MsgBox('Error Running Downloaded Setup File', mbError, MB_OK);  
    Result := True;       
  end
    else Result := True;
end;
```

Any Ideas? Everything else works fine.

---

Edit: I have a workaround that will show the details section.  This might be more appropriate anyways.  Still not sure why the Total progress is not updating.

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    idpShowDetails(True);
    IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Visible := false;
    IDPForm.TotalProgressLabel.Visible := false;
    IDPForm.TotalDownloaded.Visible := false;
    IDPForm.CurrentFileLabel.Caption := 'Downloading...';
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption := 'Downloading Setup File';
    WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := 'Please wait while the Setup file is being downloaded.';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Which progress bar? *"Total progress"* or *"Current file*"?

Comment: Not sure which one comes up by default in IDP.  There is just one progress bar.  The amount downloaded updates just not the progress bar.  It is kind of strange since it updates when I run it inside Inno.  It just does not update when I run the resultant exe.  I will try it on a different computer and see what happens.  Also, I cleaned up the code some so there are some minor edits above.

Comment: OK, so it's the *"Total progress"* - I assume that if you click on the *"Details"* button, then the *"Current file"* progress does updates, right?

Comment: Yes the Current file updates - just not the Total progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indeed get the same behavior. I do not understand why.

But as you have a single file, you can replace the total progress bar with file progress bar:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Visible := False;
    IDPForm.FileProgressBar.Top := IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Top;
    IDPForm.FileProgressBar.Visible := True;
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Visible := False;

    IDPForm.DetailsVisible := True;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I must have missed your answer while I was editing.  This will work.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I decided to change the CurrentFileLabel.Caption to Downloading... and show all the details.  Thanks again.